# HTML5/CSS3 margin commands not being recognized

Tags: html

In notepad++, the margin commands, starting at margin-top, are not recognized as keywords. This means that in my website, even though the code is correct, it is not setting the top margin or padding to the desired size. The same think is happening in both top-sidebar and bottom-sidebar. Please Help!!

```
.top-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
    margin-top: 2%
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%
    padding: 2% 3%
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
    margin-top: 2% 
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%
    padding: 2% 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors, thats why it doesn't recognize your margin properties. remeber to use `;`.

Try this:

```
.top-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 2% ;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}
```